# How can I push changes to a remote branch on GitHub without having to create a rebase node on git tree?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gerrit

I have just recently moved from Gerrit to GitHub and am currently figuring out a fitting workflow. My workflow at the present is as following:

start

`--- a (master, origin/master)`

Create branch and make changes

`--- a (master, origin/master) --- b (new_branch)`

```
git add . 
git commit 
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch
```

`--- a (master, origin/master) --- b (new_branch, origin/new_branch)`

**if** ( new_branch is fine ) =>
merge origin/new_branch to origin/master and delete origin/new_branch

```
git branch -D new_branch 
git remote prune origin #clean merged origin branches as for some reason it still appear at local
git checkout master && git pull
```

`--- a --- b (master, origin/master)`

**if** (new_branch is NOT fine) =>
edit new_branch

```
git add .
git commit --amend
```

```
--- a (master, origin/master) --- b (origin/new_branch)
     \
       --- c (new_branch)
```

at here, for some reason I can't just `git push --set-upstream origin new_branch` to push the change upstream
so I have to do a `git pull --rebase`
at this step, I have to do an excessive rebase which marks ALL of my new changes as conflicts even when they could just merge to nothingness, for example: just add a return; onto a blank line would make
it become

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    return;
>>>>>>> [demo_bazel] add dummy test
```

after the excessive rebase:

`--- a (master, origin/master) --- b (origin/new_branch) --- c (new_branch)`

only then I can finally do `git push --set-upstream origin new_branch` again

`--- a (master, origin/master) --- b --- c (new_branch, origin/new_branch)`

**My goal is, if possible, how can I make all of the changes I make on new_branch stays on only 1 node, always?** that means the last line would be without the b in between:

`--- a (master, origin/master) --- c (new_branch, origin/new_branch)`

the reason here is that I wouldn't want all the useless b nodes to bloat my git tree, in Gerrit they used to stay neatly and effortlessly in 1 git node above the master node by doing `git push ${1-origin} HEAD:refs/for/master%r=reviewer` after creating a `git commit --amend`.

I have described all of my currently working status on the above as it's a part of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for the problem above

for the following edits after the first commit, just use the below to push new changes to the remote branch:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```